# Do HTML comments get discarded while sending in mails via ExactTarget?

Tags: marketing-cloud

Does ExactTarget send in HTML comments in the email ?

I need this set because someone else (tester) wants this in the email : `href="%%view_email_url%%"`

```html
<!-- Check web view here - <a href="%%view_email_url%%">click here</a>. -->
```

Do email providers like gmail and outlook discard it ? Because I don't see this comment code in my HTML DOM element when I do inspect element.

What is the other solution to get `%%view_email_url%%` inside the email but not show it in browser based email as well as desktop clients ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gmail client and Outlook client still populate the comment section, they just don't display in the UI

For example, you can find the comment section by this way:

In **Gmail**, you can click 3 dots in the email then click on "Show original"

[image]

From there you can search with "Check web view here" text, then you can find the webpage view URL which was generated by Marketing Cloud.

Or in **Outlook**, you can click on the email message with

[image]

Then from there, just right click and view source. You can search like the same way above to find the webpage view URL